# How to update multiple dashboard components on click - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I've found it very difficult to find help online with this issue as no examples seem to match my use case. I'm basically wanting to check if I am on the right track in my approach.I have a single page Vue app:

[image]

Each row on the right is a component. On the left are listed three data sets that each possess values for the fields in the dashboard. I want it to be so that when you click on a dataset, each field updates for that set.
So if you click on 'Beds', the title becomes 'Beds' and all the fields populate the specific data for beds.

I want to do this without having separate pages for each dataset since that would seem to defeat the point of using a reactive framework like Vue. Only the embedded components should change, not the page.

I have installed Vue Router and have explored using slots and dynamic components but it is very hard to understand.

If someone experienced in Vue could just let me know the right broad approach to this I then know what I need to look into, at the moment it is difficult to know where to start. Thank you

Comment: At least show what have you tried

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Vuex` for that purpose.

Add property to the state, `dataset` for example. And mutation to change it. Every component on the right side should use that `this.$store.state.dataset` (or through mapState) for its own purposes. So when you're selecting one of listed datasets on the left side, it will mutate dataset in store with its own data.

Something like that:

**store** (there are alternate version, where we can use getter, but its little bit more complicated for just an example).

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    dataset: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    setDataset(state, payload) {
      Vue.set(state, 'dataset', payload);
    }
  }
});
```

**one of the right side component**

```js
computed: {
  dataset() {
    return this.$store.state.dataset;
  },
  keywords() {
    return this.dataset.keywords;
  },
  volume() {
    return this.dataset.volume;
  }
}
```

**left menu**
template:

```html
<a href="#" v-for="dataset in datasets" @click="changeDataset(dataset)" :key="dataset.id">{{dataset.title}}</a>
```

code:

```js
data() {
  return {
    datasets: [{
      id: 1,
      title: 'Sofas',
      keywords: ['foo'],
      volume: 124543
    }]
  }
},
methods: {
  changeDataset(dataset) {
    this.$store.commit('setDataset', dataset);
  }
}
```

`datasets` is your data which you're loading from server.

**BUT** You can use some global variable for that, without `Vuex`. Maybe Vue `observable`, added in 2.6.